# Speaker clustering/diarization

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am working on the problem of speaker clustering. I am using k-means clustering. The ground truth cluster values and k-mean cluster values do not correspond due to different methods of labelling (manually labelled for ground truth and via scikit's k-means function). So I need to find all permutations of matching values and choose the matching values with the highest percentage of match/correctness. I have a ground truth npy array and a labels_by_kmeans npy array as shown below:

**Ground truth**

[image: Ground truth]

**Labels by Kmeans**

[image: Labels by kmeans]

As you can see, arrays 0 and 2 in both tables have 0s and 2s,3s that correspond to each other. However, in array 1 5s seems to corresponds to 0s. I am trying to find the best fit for 0s in ground truth in Labels by k-means.

How can I do this via code?

Answer (score 1):

Implement the

[Hungarian matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)

It will find the best mapping.